# MVC Application not displaying DB records using EntityFramework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am new to MVC and I'm trying to display a list of records but I keep getting the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Induction.Employee]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Induction.Models.AnEmployee]'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Induction.Employee]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Induction.Models.AnEmployee]'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Induction.Employee]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Induction.Models.AnEmployee]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9869829
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.3752.0
```

I'm not sure what the issue is because on my previous attempt, I could display the records but when a user navigates to a new page ad tries to save data, I would get the same error which is why I started over.

Controller code:

```
namespace Induction.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       
        EmployeeDbEntities _context = new EmployeeDbEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Employees.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Induction.Models.AnEmployee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeNumberCS)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IDNumberCS)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeNameCS)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeSurnameCS)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumOfDepCS)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RaceRef)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GenderRef)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeNumberCS)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDNumberCS)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeNameCS)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeSurnameCS)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumOfDepCS)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RaceRef)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GenderRef)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.IdCS">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.IdCS">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.IdCS">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

AnEmployee.cs Class

```
 public class AnEmployee
    {
        public int IdCS { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNumberCS { get; set; }
        public string IDNumberCS { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeNameCS { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeSurnameCS { get; set; }
        public int NumOfDepCS { get; set; }
        public int EmpGenderIdCS { get; set; }
        public int EmpRaceIdCS { get; set; }

        //Navigation Propeties EDMX
        public ICollection<Gender> GenderRef { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Race> RaceRef { get; set; }
    }
```

GenderClass.cs

```
public class GenderClass
    {
        public int GenderIdRefCS { get; set; }
        public string GenderDescrRefCS { get; set; }

        //Navigation Propeties EDMX
        public Employee employee { get; set; }
    }
```

RaceClass.cs

```
public class RaceClass
    {
        public int RaceIdRefCS { get; set; }
        public string RaceDescrRefCS { get; set; }

        //Navigation Propeties EDMX
        public Employee employee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the stacktrace mentions the exact error, in your case you are getting a list of Employee in the controller and passing it as the viewmodel. But the viewmodel expects an IEnumerable of AnEmployee, hence the casting error.

You should convert List to the correct list of AnEmployee in the controller before returning it to the view.